# Re-define "stringLiteral" token in Parsec.Token

Tags: parsing, haskell, pascal, parsec

I am developing Pascal language parser in Haskell using Parsec library and I need to re-define some tokens defined in Parsec.Token class.

Speeking of it, here is my case:

I need to change how `stringLiteral` token is matched. In default definition, it is something `between char '"'` ([see this](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/latest/doc/html/src/Text-Parsec-Token.html#TokenParser)), but I need it to be `between '\''` (apostrophes). How can I do this modification to Parsec behavior?

Thanks!!!

Comment: You have to write an alternative `stringLiteral` parser. Unfortunately you can't customize it through the `LanguageDef` like you can with comments.

Comment: I see, but how do I force lexical parser to use my alternative `stringLiteral` parser instead of the default one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are talking about adjusting the field of a data type named `GenTokenParser`.  It looks like you are using a function that automatically fills in the data type with sensible defaults and you just want to adjust one thing, here you go:

```
 myMakeTokenParser langDef =
    let default = makeTokenParser langDef
    in default { stringLiteral = newStringLit }
  where
  newStringLit = lexeme (
                      do{ str <- between (char '\'')
                                         (char '\'' <?> "end of string")
                                         (many stringChar)
                        ; return (foldr (maybe id (:)) "" str)
                        }
                      <?> "literal string")
```

Comment: I am getting this error: `Couldn't match expected type P.GenTokenParser s0 u0 m0
                with actual type ParsecT s1 u1 m1 a0
    In the first argument of P.lexeme, ...`

I am using import `import qualified Text.Parsec.Token as P`, so there is `P.lexeme`

Comment: Right, I just copied and pasted part of the lexer from parsec.  You can copy and paste a large section of code from the linked module or make your own string lexer and put it on the RHS of newStringLit.